# installing SNMP in Windows x32 Customized Image

Tags: windows-7, snmp

I'm working in a environment of 40 machines, I've already installed snmp in 38 machines normally, but 2 of them appear to have been installed with a customized windows image, there is no OptionalFeatures, there is no ocsetup.exe, so I could not able to install SNMP.

I tried to copy OptionalFeatures and ocsetup from another machine, but it don't work.
For now I cannot simple format these two computer, it's possible to install it using another way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please try [DISM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824822.aspx), running from an [elevated](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) cmd.exe, to enable a Feature:

```
Dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:SNMP
```

Comment: This did not worked, I tried some others walkthought and none worked, so I decided to talk with the computer owner and format his computers.

Comment: post the DISM.log and the CBS.log